# In bazel testing C++ gtest, how do I create a sandbox per TEST_P parameter so I can look at their content?

Tags: linux, googletest, bazel

I have a test I run with

`bazel test //test/directory:my_test --sandbox_debug`

I want to take a look at the content of output in sandbox in `~/.cache/bazel/.../sandbox_place`. Now the test involves paramterized test `TEST_P` initialized to several cases. When the bazel test is ran, I realized it's using the same sandbox so it deletes everything in the previous parameter case. I know they exist temporarily by outputting different dummy file name in sandbox and quickly going to the directory but they're quickly overwritten when moved to next `TEST_P` case.

How can I save individual test case and its sandbox per TEST_P parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Run a single test case at a time with [--gtest_filter](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests), which you can pass through bazel's [--test_arg](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_arg). That way, no other test cases run before you have a chance to look at the result. You can get the full test case names from the test output `RUN` lines and then copy/paste them into the flag value.

For example, `bazel test //test/directory:my_test --sandbox_debug --test_arg=---gtest_filter=Values/MyTest.Something/1`.